# Updating the values of one column in a pandas dataframe based on input proportion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Some column of pandas dataframe having no. unique value (say 4). Those value will have some initial proportion across all rows. I need to change that giving input of desired proportion. Let's say I have 100 rows and a Column name `city` having values in given proportion.

```
Mumbai  30%
Kolkata 40%
Chennai 10%
Delhi   20%
```

Now i need to change the values across the column so that I get my desired proportion (or structure of data).

```
Mumbai  20%
Kolkata 50%
Chennai 20%
Delhi   10%
```

While doing this **I want to make sure that when changing the value of rows having city `Mumbai` from 25% to 20% I should keep 20% of them same as before and only alter the rest 5% i.e. not to clear all the values and populate according to new proportion** I am trying to do this in pandas dataframe. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: So say my column looks like this with 10 rows.

```
1   Mumbai
2   Mumbai 
3   Mumbai
4   Kolkata
5   Kolkata
6   Kolkata
7   Kolkata
8   Chennai
9   Delhi
10  Delhi
```

Now i would like it to be changed some thing like given the above change.

```
1   Mumbai
2   Mumbai 
3   Kolkata
4   Kolkata
5   Kolkata
6   Kolkata
7   Kolkata
8   Chennai
9   Chennai
10  Delhi
```

I didn't made it random. new rows having Mumbai are subset of the last one.

Comment: question is unclear. how did you decide to remove 5% from Mumbai and add 5% to Kolkata? what are the inputs?

Comment: @sathyz mumbai or kolkata is just an example. I have to change proportion for some external reasons. I know the desired proportion. So it is an input.

Comment: Could you construct the both the input dataframes. Given a dataframe of 100 rows, are you aggregating the dataframe to arrive at what you have shown here. It would clear, if you give steps you have followed, what are you expecting, what have you tried etc.

Comment: @sathyz see i have made some edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter 
import pandas as pd

def set_proportion(df, column, new_proportion):
    proportion = (df[column].value_counts() / df.shape[0]).to_dict()
    prop_diff = {key: new_proportion[key] - proportion[key] for key in new_proportion}
    prop_diff_cnt = {key: int(round(value * df.shape[0])) for key, value in prop_diff.items()}
    to_add = {key: diff for key, diff in prop_diff_cnt.items() if diff > 0}
    to_remove = {key: diff for key, diff in prop_diff_cnt.items() if diff < 0}
    to_add = sum(([key] * diff for key, diff in to_add.items()), [])
    to_remove = sum(([key] * -diff for key, diff in to_remove.items()), [])
    # group to counter to do updates to the dataframe in bulk, one update per each *unique* replacement pair
    counter = Counter(list(zip(to_remove, to_add)))
    for (remove, add), count in counter.items():
        df.loc[df[df[column] == remove].iloc[-count:].index, column] = add    

df = pd.DataFrame(["Mumbai"] * 3 + ["Kolkata"] * 4 + ["Chennai"] + ["Delhi"] * 2, columns=['city']) 
print df 
    city
0   Mumbai
1   Mumbai 
2   Mumbai
3   Kolkata
4   Kolkata
5   Kolkata
6   Kolkata
7   Chennai
8   Delhi
9   Delhi    

set_proportion(df, 'city', {'Mumbai': 0.2, 'Kolkata': 0.5, 'Chennai': 0.2, 'Delhi': 0.1})
print df 
      city
0  Mumbai 
1  Mumbai 
2  Chennai
3  Kolkata
4  Kolkata
5  Kolkata
6  Kolkata
7  Chennai
8  Delhi  
9  Kolkata

# set_proportion modifies the original dataframe, so we need to reinitialize it
df = pd.DataFrame(["Mumbai"] * 3 + ["Kolkata"] * 4 + ["Chennai"] + ["Delhi"] * 2, columns=['city']) 

set_proportion(df, 'city', {'Mumbai': 0.2, 'Kolkata': 0.1, 'Chennai': 0.3, 'Delhi': 0.4})
print df 

      city
0  Mumbai 
1  Mumbai 
2  Delhi  
3  Kolkata
4  Delhi  
5  Chennai
6  Chennai
7  Chennai
8  Delhi  
9  Delhi
```

Comment: This works, Thanks. One more thing, For some columns they are in range. i.e `1960-80 :30%` what changes are required?

Comment: I don't think any changes are required. The range columns contain strings, right?